# Does not show anything in Parsing JSON for Recycler View

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I follow the online tutorial to build the Parsing JSON for Recycler View application. However, it does not show anything in the application. I don't know what happen about it. Can anyone help me to figure out the problem? Thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAisC.png)

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<net.smallacademy.songslist.Song> songs;
    private static String JSON_URL = "http://starlord.hackerearth.com/studio";
    Adapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.songsList);
        songs = new ArrayList<>();
        extractSongs();

    }

    private void extractSongs() {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, JSON_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject songObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                        net.smallacademy.songslist.Song song = new net.smallacademy.songslist.Song();
                        song.setTitle(songObject.getString("song").toString());
                        song.setArtists(songObject.getString("artists".toString()));
                        song.setCoverImage(songObject.getString("cover_image"));
                        song.setSongURL(songObject.getString("url"));
                        songs.add(song);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
                adapter = new Adapter(getApplicationContext(),songs);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("tag", "onErrorResponse: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });

        queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
}
```

Song.java

```
public class Song {
    private String title;
    private String artists;
    private String coverImage;
    private String songURL;

    public  Song(){}
    public Song(String title,String artists,String coverImage,String songURL){
        this.title = title;
        this.artists = artists;
        this.coverImage = coverImage;
        this.songURL = songURL;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getArtists() {
        return artists;
    }

    public void setArtists(String artists) {
        this.artists = artists;
    }

    public String getCoverImage() {
        return coverImage;
    }

    public void setCoverImage(String coverImage) {
        this.coverImage = coverImage;
    }

    public String getSongURL() {
        return songURL;
    }

    public void setSongURL(String songURL) {
        this.songURL = songURL;
    }
}
```

Adapter.java

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<net.smallacademy.songslist.Song> songs;

    public Adapter(Context ctx, List<net.smallacademy.songslist.Song> songs) {
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
        this.songs = songs;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_layout,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.songTitle.setText(songs.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.songArtists.setText(songs.get(position).getArtists());
        Picasso.get().load(songs.get(position).getCoverImage()).into(holder.songCoverImage);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return songs.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView songTitle, songArtists;
        ImageView songCoverImage;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            songTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
            songArtists = itemView.findViewById(R.id.songArtist);
            songCoverImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.coverImage);

        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/songsList"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

custom_list_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/coverImage"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/songTitle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Song Title"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/coverImage"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/songArtist"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:text="Song Artist"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/coverImage"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/songTitle"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Log the data that you get from the response and see if you are able to get them, if no then add the JSON response to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please transfer this below code into onCreate method

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
```

and then change this both tag of Recyclerview

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: I followed your method to do it but it does not work.

Comment: are you getting proper response from API?